# Обновление записей в MySQL с ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE без учета пустых ячеек

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, xls

Здравия прочитавшим!

При обновлении данных в базе используется файл *.xls, в нем бывают пустые ячейки в записях - по задумке, надо что бы они не стирали имеющиеся записи  в базе данных, если совпали.
Делаю стандартное обновление записей путем провоцирования конфликта ключей по полю ID

```
INSERT INTO `orders` (`id`,`name`,`status`) 
VALUES ('1','Иван','OK'),('2','Марья','OK') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
`name` = VALUES(`name`),
`status` = VALUES(`status`);
```

Но к сожалению, пустые ячейки стирают соответствующие записи в базе. Все обновляет нормально. 
Пробовал посредством PHP, но ничего дельного не приходило в голову.
Кто сталкивался с подобными случаями, может есть идеи?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> в нем бывают пустые ячейки в записях

Что попадает в формируемый запрос в секцию VALUES, если некая ячейка "пустая"? небось пустая строка? т.е. получается нечто вроде

```
INSERT INTO `orders` (`id`,`name`,`status`) 
VALUES ('1','Иван','OK'),('2','Марья','')
```

Верно?

Если так - то вместо пустой строки формируйте там Null, а в секции ODKU сделайте соотв. обёртку:

```
INSERT INTO `orders` (`id`,`name`,`status`) 
VALUES ('1','Иван','OK'),('2','Марья',Null) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
`name` = COALESCE(VALUES(`name`),`name`),
`status` = COALESCE(VALUES(`status`),`status`);
```

Comment: Спасибо! Получилось! Класс!